# What happened to my question on discrete valuation rings?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, deleted-questions, closed-questions, auto-delete

I asked a question whose title was **Two discrete valuation rings one of which is contained in another**([Two discrete valuation rings, one contained into another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184744/two-discrete-valuation-rings-one-of-which-is-contained-in-another)). It was closed, but I have no idea why it was closed.

The quesion was:
Let $A$ and $B$ be discrete valuation rings having the same field of fractions.
Suppose $A \subset B$. Then $A = B$?

I wrote the motivation since some users tend to vote to close a question without it.

Comment: At the end of you question page http://math.stackexchange.com/users/217571/william-curtis?tab=questions follow the link "deleted recent questions" you should find the question there. If you post the link to the question here you might get some more information. Without seeing the post it is hard to tell. And for everybody but you and mods it is hard to locate the question.

Comment: @quid Thanks for your info.

Answer (score 20):

[The question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184744/two-discrete-valuation-rings-one-of-which-is-contained-in-another) was automatically deleted by the [Community♦](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) bot:

> Apr 11 at 0:16    history     deleted     Community♦  Scheduled: RemoveDeadQuestions

It had a score of $-2$, was more than 30 days old, and had no answer. Such questions are [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006) network wide. Your question was never closed, old negatively scored questions without activity are deleted whether closed or not. Closed questions are deleted sooner (after nine days, iirc) when they are negatively scored and have no positively scored answer.

As [quid](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/users/85306/quid) just commented, for questions not older than $60$ days, you can find these questions yourself from the "deleted recent questions" link at the bottom of the "questions" tab in your profile.

Comment: I strongly disagree with this feature of the system. Voting can be highly subjective. Any users can downvote for whatever reason.

Comment: @WilliamCurtis: While voting can be highly subjective I think that this mechanism leading to deletion generally works fine. An unfortunate side-effect is that questions in tags with less viewers occasionally become collateral damage - particularly when the tag has a keen, critical follower casting a relatively large number of downvotes. The remedy is, of course, that users interested in higher level tags should vote more often. FWIW I would myself vote to undelete the thread in question were my not vote immediately binding. Looks like it's well on its way to undeletion anyway :-)

Comment: Now undeleted (but the one answer that was posted is still deleted).

Comment: @GerryMyerson The answer was deleted by its author, otherwise the question wouldn't have been deleted in the first place. If the state remains as is (negative score, no answer), the question will be deleted again when the script next runs, however, so to keep it undeleted, the state should be changed soon. If you know who can answer it, bringing their attention to the question could help.